# How to draw the text vertically in Pie Slice?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-wheel

I Need to make Pie chart like below images and there slice text should be vertically (start text near radius to out)

[small slice text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkpb0.jpg)